# Re-authorize hundreds Google scripts indefinitely

Tags: google-apps-script

I have about 700 Google sheets, running scripts.
For too many years now, I have to re-authorize these scripts indefinitely.
Of course, I searched the net, I simplified my scripts to minimize the number of services called. Recently, I was hoping that the Google Alpha V8 script could have helped me, but no, definitely no. Still no solution.
My hundreds of sheets are opened by the employees of my company, therefore hundreds of scripts linked to these sheets are automatically used thanks to triggers (simple and installable triger)

It seems obvious that there is a limitation on the number of scripts allowed at the same time. This limitation having been visibly reached for years, I have to re-authorize, every day, some scripts. But by doing this, I guess I am revoking so many other scripts. How Google decides to revoke this or that script, I don't know. I guess the least used.
Why this limitation? Is it possible to increase it?
If not, what is the solution?

I add I found this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization , which is talking about OAuth application user limits (at the very bottom of the page) . I wonder if this could help me.

Thank you.

---

I worked on my topic, reading a lot of english docs... I painly read and slowly understood them. I hope so !
As I could expected, I hit on restrictions, placed by my organization, I imagine. I am unable to create project. See [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDjAM.jpg)
In the same time, and strangely, I own several projects. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDhUr.jpg). I don't know why they exist, even if I recognize their names which are those of several of my scripts.

Anyway if I want to publish my script as an Add-on, I have to "link" my script to a "standard GCP project".
As it is impossible to create specific projects, I tried to follow a google procedure, consisting to link my script to an existing project. But as it was expected, it does not work either [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rnzg.jpg)

If someone had a good suggestion, it would be welcome.
Thx.
JM.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Apps Script Quotas https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas? You might have e.g. too many simultaneous executions or hit the maximum runtime per day or other limits. An obvious (but paying) solution would be upgrading your account. If this is not an option - do your scripts all do the same? You might think about creating one (or multiple) Editor Add-on which allows you to run the same script on different documents.

Comment: Hello ziganotschka.
1- Yes I already had a look on this quotas board, but I don't find any relevant parameter which could help me.  
2- Concerning the paying account, it is already the case since more than 10 years. My company is Valeo, which owns about 100 000 accounts.
3- Yes, 98 % of my scripts are the same, because these sheets are automaticaly created from 3 templates, by users, thanks to 8 forms. 
This solution works since 6-7 years.
4- I think I already explored the Add-on solution, but is there not limitation ? I will  see again.
Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Everything has limitations :-) But if you have an Add-on you need to install it only once to make it work for all the 700 sheets, rather than creating 700 scripts, so you are less likely to hit whatever quota.

Comment: I agree that everything has limits, but I expected a much higher limitation on the number of scripts.
For example, the limit of calendar events created is 5000 per day ...
As I write in the other answer, I use the notion of library, and also, installable on-open triggers.
I guess I will have to stop the use of library, but I will have to  keep the trigger as the add-on will have to be executed each time the sheets are opened.
I expected a simpler solution, because I'm not a big developer, and for example, the interface of Google Cloud Platform is scary ... ^^

Answer (score 1):

Convert your scripts to an add-on. Then these add-ons can be shared across users and spreadsheets, and you can actually reduce the number of places you need to maintain code. You can view the publishing guide here: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons

A second solution is to create a standard Google Cloud Platform project and change (some/all of) your scripts to use it, rather than their own hidden GCP project. More info about this step: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects

Note that both of these solutions will result in sharing of certain quota limits, which may mean you need to redesign or update how you do things
However, both of these changes provide increased visibility into the errors that your scripts encounter, as you no longer have 700+ places to check for error reports, just a 1 or a handful.

Comment: Hello tehhowch.
Lot of thanks to you.
I search a solution since years. I expected a simple one, because I am not a great developper. With Google solutions, there are often unexpected (bad) surprises ^^
I will see again this Add-on solution. It seems to me that there were limitations. But I don't really know anymore...
Some concepts are not very easy to handle, or to assimilate, and of course, english is not an help. I would prefer that the whole world speaks french...
Concerning standard Google Cloud Platform project, I have to see that.
Thank you again.
JM.

Comment: I will add I used the notion of library. So, the main code is in a kind of generic code, and my hundreds of scripts, linked to as many google sheets, are in fact very tiny, very short.
If necessary, by changing only the main script allows to impact hundreds of scripts.
I hope this way to work is compatible with Add-on or Cloud Platform project solution..

Comment: @jean-marie it is not the same. Each new bound script that installs a library is a new project, and the authorization for that project is what you are currently fighting against. Installing an add-on, or changing the GCP project of each tiny bound script, is what you must do